# How to group row updates based on column values?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
+------------------------------+
| Name,Class,Value,Class_Total |
+------------------------------+
| John  ,A  ,10,        0      |
| Jake  ,A  ,22,        0      |
| Jill  ,B  ,34,        0      |
+------------------------------+
```

And I would like to run an UPDATE query that populates the Class_Total with the total for each class i.e the result would be

```
+------------------------------+
| Name,Class,Value,Class_Total |
+------------------------------+
| John  ,A  ,10,        32     |
| Jake  ,A  ,22,        32     |
| Jill  ,B  ,34,        34     |
+------------------------------+
```

Currently I have this

```
UPDATE  dbo.Contrived
SET Class_Total = (SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM dbo.Contrived
)
```

But this puts the total for all classes in the Class_Total not just the class the row belongs to, I need to somehow group the items by class. I know I could do a

```
WHERE Class ='A'
```

In the Select but I would like to do it automatically for lots of classes.
Hope that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple sub query:

```
UPDATE c 
SET c.Class_Total = (SELECT SUM(c2.Value)
                     FROM dbo.Contrived c2
                     WHERE c2.Class = c.Class)
FROM dbo.Contrived c
```

<kbd>[**Demo-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/457b6/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `CTE`:

```
;with T as(
    select *, SUM(Value) over(partition by Class) sm
    From dbo.Contrived
) update T set Class_Total=sm
```